# React / "react-custom-scrollbars" / save scrollbar positions for each column in the local storage and restore after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, scrollbar

I use Scrollbars from "react-custom-scrollbars" in React. I have 3 columns which each has own Scrollbar. I need to save each scroll position in local Storage and restore in after the page reload in way that the thumbs stay there where it was before refreshing the page.

My code in Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-scrollbar-columns-zym15f?file=/src/App.js

I tried to work with GPT but any code I got worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.